# Slice Dataframe in a Loop R

Tags: r, loops, csv

I have a dataframe called `Results` with `nrows = 288` and `ncol = 4`.

I have no experience with loops and would like to run a loop where I can delete rows 1-10, then rows 11-20, 21-30. etc etc. Saving the result as a CSV after each loop.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` like :

```
n <- nrow(Results)

lapply(seq(1,n, 10), function(x) 
     write.csv(Results[-(x:min((x+9), n))], paste0("data", x, "-", x+9, ".csv")))
```

This will write csvs in your working directory named `"data1-10.csv"`, `"data11-20.csv"` etc.